# RuntimeError: cannot open, when using arcpy outside ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, cursor, delete, runtimeerror

When I ran the below code, I got a runtimeerror: can't open the shapefile. The file was not occupied by ArcGIS. I even restarted the computer, but it still gave me the error. However, I can run the code in the built-in python with ArcGIS. Why?

```
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()

import arcpy

fc = r'C:\Users\TL\Desktop\1016test\CursorDelEmpRd\TigerMerge.shp'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "FULLNAME") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == '':
            cursor.deleteRow()


stop = timeit.default_timer()

RunningTime = stop - start
print "The running time of the whole process is: ", RunningTime
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you move the shapefile somewhere else, like C:\Temp and repoint your script to that location and run it?  If it still doesn't work it will rule out the location as the problem

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Have you tried running it from IDLE as a test?